# Javascript callback functions execution

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm not sure the correct term for this. But I want to write a function that accepts another function and execute it.
For eg.

```
function test(data, aFunc) {
   var newData = data + " Shawn";

   aFunc.call(newData);
}

test("hello", function(data){
   alert(data);
});
```

Data is supposed to contain "hello Shawn" string. Help me rewrite this the correct way please.

Comment: The term you are looking for is "higher-order function"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first argument of the [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Function/call) method is used to set the `this` keyword (the function context) explicitly, inside the invoked function, e.g.:

```
function test(data, aFunc) {
   var newData = data + " Shawn";

   aFunc.call(newData);
}

test("hello", function () {
   alert(this); // hello Shawn
});
```

If you want to invoke a function without caring about the context (the `this` keyword), you can invoke it directly without `call`:

```
function test(data, aFunc) {
   var newData = data + " Shawn";

   aFunc(newData); // or aFunc.call(null, newData);
}

test("hello", function (data) {
   alert(data);
});
```

Note that if you simply invoke a function like `aFunc(newData);` or you use the `call` or `apply` methods with the `this` argument set as `null` or `undefined`, the `this` keyword inside the invoked function will refer to the Global object (`window`).

Answer (score 2):

Looks fine but you can just change

```
aFunc.call(newData);
```

to

```
aFunc(newData);
```

Answer (score 1):

You were close. The first argument to "call" is the "scope" argument. In this case, it doesn't matter what it is, because you're not using "this" anywhere in your anonymous function, so any value will suffice.

```
function test(data, aFunc) {
   var newData = data + " Shawn";

   aFunc.call(this, newData);
}

test("hello", function(data){
   alert(data);
});
```